# Loop filtering Custom Post Types and/or Categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, filters

I've been looking at the [Search & Filter plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/), and as much as it would essentially get the job done, I need more flexibility to filter posts on a page based on a selection.

I'm not sure where to start.

What would the code for a loop look like if I wanted to filter a News Custom Post Type and a few other posts categories on a page?

Comment: This is too general, have you made any attempts yet? if so please paste them here as this is quite a task.

Comment: @AhmedMahdi I was pretty clear in that I don't know where to start. Thanks for the -1

Comment: Apologies. Can you please edit your question and include a bit more detail (perhaps example of what you're trying to do) that will help. I didn't really mean anything, the downvote due to small details provided in question, so I kindly ask you to edit it and give us more details, we want to help you :)